# Pointers and references

Tags: c++, pointers

I am currently learning c++ and pointers inside of c++. I am curious as to why I get a different memory address when I reference a pointer and why it isn't the same as the reference to the variable. Here is my super simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int n = 50;
int *p = &n;
cout << "Number: " << n << endl;
cout << "Number with &: " << &n << endl;
cout << "Pointer: " << p << endl;
cout << "Pointer with *: " << *p << endl;
cout << "Pointer with &: " << &p << endl;
}
```

Why does &p give me a different address than "&n" and "p"? Thank you

Comment: &n is an address of n, &p is an address of p. Why should they be equal? There are no references in your code. & is the address operator there.

Comment: `&p` is the address of `p` pointer, which is different (probably just after) `&n` which is the address of `n` value.

Comment: p is a pointer of n, so it has its's own address, not relevant to the address to n?

Comment: also note - none of these things is a reference.  `int &r = n;` would be a reference

Comment: Imagine physically pointing at someone. You have your own physical location (`&p`) and so does the person you're pointing to (`&n`). So of course they're different.

Comment: You visit a web page, at address (URL) N, and it says "50". You then visit another page, at address P, and it shows a link to N. Do you expect both pages to have the same address? Do the page addresses need to be related in any way, except for the fact that visiting P shows the other address N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you declare an int variable n with the **value** of 50. This value will be stored at an address in memory. When you print n you get the value that the variable n holds.

Then you declare a pointer *p pointing to the variable n. This is a new variable that will hold the **address** to the variable n, where it is stored in memory. When you print p you will get back that **address**.

You can also ask for the **address** to where the value of n is stored by using the & symbol. This is what you get when you print &n, this will be the same as the pointer p.

Using the * symbol before a pointer will dereference it, meaning instead of returning the address that is the pointer, it will return the **value** that the pointer is pointing to. In your case this is an int with the value 50.

Lastly, the pointer *p that you declared is stored at it's own address in memory. Just as you could get the **address** to the variable n with the & symbol, you can get the **address** of p by using &p. This will be different from the address of n since it's not where 50 is stored, it's where the pointer to the value 50 is stored.